# Difference between [0-9]* and [0-9]

Tags: regex

I am learning regexes and found some codes so I tested in my terminal and got results given below

```
$ echo "my version 3.8.0" | grep -o '[0-9.]*'
3.8.0
$ echo "my version 3.8.0" | grep -o '[0-9]*'
3
8
0
$ echo "my version 3.8.0" | grep -o '[0-9]'
3
8
0
```

Why last two expressions are giving same output so I want to know how ? And one more thing , the first expression output is in one line where rest two expressions output is in multiple lines why ? I am new to regexes and its very confusing

Finally I am just want to know the working flow of above expressions or line of code

Comment: Try changing the version from `3.8.0` to `38.0`

Comment: Single digits match both `[0-9]` (any single digit) and `[0-9]*` (zero or more digits, except that it isn't matching all the sequences of zero digits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, quick note:

```
[0-9] matches exactly one digit
[0-9]* matches a sequence of digits of any length
```

In your case, the largest sequence of digits in `3.8.0` is either `3` or `8` or `0` as they're separated by `.`

If your version were `38.1.0`, for instance, then you would see a difference:

```
[0-9] would give 3, 8, 1, 0
[0-9]* would give 38, 1, 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9.]*
```

matches zero or more characters from the set `0123456789.`. It can therefore match the entire string `3.8.0`.

```
[0-9]*
```

matches zero or more digits. Therefore it can match each of the digits but has to omit the dots. You get three matches; one is displayed per line.

```
[0-9]
```

matches exactly one digit. Since `3.8.0` only contains single digits, the output of the last two regexes is identical. That would change with inputs like `3.8.10`.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` at the end of any range(or character) makes it count all occurrences matching the range(character) zero or more number of times.

For example, `[0-9]*` on `38.65.32` will give you

```
38
65
32
```

But, `[0-9]` on the same will give you

```
3
8
6
5
3
2
```

Answer (score 1):

`[0-9.]*` will give you `3.8.0` because you use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match   either a digit or a dot zero or more times matching all the characters.

`[0-9]*` Will match zero or more times a digit using a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html). Since the example data contains single digits separated by a dot, not more than a single digit can be matched because the dot will not be matched.

`[0-9]` Will match a single digit without a quantifier.

If for example your string was `"my version 3.80.0"`:

`[0-9.]*` Would match `3.80.0`

`[0-9]*` Would match `3` `80` `0`

`[0-9]` Would match `3` `8` `0` `0`

Comment: Thnx for reference links